# IBM DB2 Select all query result only part of the database

Tags: jupyter-notebook, db2, ibm-watson

I'm using Jupyter notebook in Watson studio to query data from db2 using ibm_db_dbi python library.

```
db2_pipeline_connection_connection = dbi.connect(db2_pipeline_connection_dsn)
   
query = 'SELECT count("SALE_ID") FROM "DS_DATA"."SALES"'
db2_data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=db2_pipeline_connection_connection)

db2_pipeline_connection_connection.close()
```

result is 721152 which is true, but when I try below query

```
db2_pipeline_connection_connection = dbi.connect(db2_pipeline_connection_dsn)
   
query = 'SELECT * FROM "DS_DATA"."SALES"'
db2_data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=db2_pipeline_connection_connection)

db2_pipeline_connection_connection.close()
```

it only result **270845 rows**

How can I get the entire database using this method?

Comment: Have you verified the results of both statements without using python (for example querying Db2 from the command-line, or from a JDBC gui tool) ?  There are no facts in your question about versions of python, of ibm_db, or version of Db2 etc, or whether you have any exception handlers or whether there are any warnings etc.

Comment: yep, checked with DB2 query and also downloaded the csv, it has 721152 rows.
used python v3.7, ibm_db v3.0.2,  ibm_db_dbi v3.0.2 and DB2 v11.5.1.0 no warnings at all. but this issue is only for the sales data (mentioned db2 table), for other tables I don't have any issues like this. kind of a odd situation

Comment: This kind of issue is difficult to troubleshoot from remote. Things are rarely what they seem on the surface. If the issue is table specific, examine the table definition and the query. If the issue is volume specific, eliminate that. Just basic PD/PSI techniques at your end will solve this.